# How to place widgets next to each other?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a simple GUI program to manage priorities. I am having trouble placing button widgets next to each other. It is somehow logical to me that if I want three buttons (Add, Remove, Edit) to place next to each other, I should use column = 0 for Add, column = 1 for Remove and column = 2 for Edit. Anyway, this is what I get:

[image]

Here is the createWidgets function:

```
def createWidgets(self):

    listBox = Listbox(width = 30).grid(row=1, column = 0)

    Button(self.root,
                text = "Add",
                command = self.addItem).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    Button(self.root,
           text="Remove",
           command = self.removeItem).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W)


    Button(self.root,
        text="Edit",
        command = self.editItem).grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W)

    textBox = Text(height = 10, width = 30).grid(row = 3)
```

Comment: Use the `columnspan` option:

   ` textBox = Text(height = 10, width = 30).grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E+N+S)`

(and specify the column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to break your UI down into regions, and manage each region independently. It's much easier than trying to cram everything into one big grid, especially when you have widgets with very different sizes.

Create three frames: one for the top, one for the group of buttons, and one for the bottom. You can then use `pack` to place them top-to-bottom:

```
top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

(the use of `expand` depends on if you want that frame to expand when the window is made larger)

Once you've done that, you can tackle each region separately. For example, you can make the buttons children of the button frame, and use `.pack(side='left')` to get them to be left-aligned. The other widgets can also use `pack` if they are the only widgets in each of the other frames, or you can use `grid`.

You will find that just a few minutes organizing your UI before starting to code will make a big difference in how easy it is to create and maintain.

### Example:

```
def createWidgets(self):
    topFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    bottomFrame = tk.Frame(self)

    topFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    bottomFrame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    listBox = tk.Listbox(topFrame, width=30)
    listBox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Add").pack(side="left")
    tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Remove").pack(side="left")
    tk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Edit").pack(side="left")

    textBox = tk.Text(bottomFrame, height=10, width=30)
    textBox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`columnspan`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) option for:

```
textBox = Text(height = 10, width = 30).grid(row = 3, column=0, columnspan=3) # specify the column also
```

and

```
listBox = Listbox(width = 30).grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
textBox = Text(height = 10, width = 30).grid(row = 3)
```

tkinter automatically sets `column = 0` and because `textBox` has a width of 30 the first column is stretched to a width of 30. It is possible to place `textBox` so that it occupies all columns by using the `columnspan` parameter:

```
textBox = Text(height = 10, width = 30).grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
```

Because `listBox` also has a width of 30, you should also use `columnspan` here:

```
listBox = Listbox(width = 30).grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
```

A comprehensive guide for the grid method is [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: It's a bit better, but still it doesn't look like it should be looking: [link](https://s12.postimg.org/ocx5rko5p/Screenshot_at_2017-03-31_21-57-14.png)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that you should also add the `columnspan` parameter to listBox. This was already mentioned by Billal BEGUERADJ in his answer.